# How can I type into the chrome omnibox/address bar using selenium webdriver?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I want to use Selenium webdriver to type into the chrome omnibox (address bar) to check that an extension is being targeted. I know how to send keys using selenium, but not how to send them to the omnibox. I've been googling this for a while, but I'm not sure how to go about it. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out it's not possible to type into the omnibox as it is outside the scope of Selenium.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% positive but from my understanding of Selenium I would be surprised if you can do that, since Selenium is for automating the web and web elements etc. and what your trying to do is automate the browser application.